# How to describe the quotient group $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z / \langle (4, -6)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

While solving a problem on group theory, I encountered the quotient group $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z / \langle (4, -6)\rangle$. Here $\mathbb Z$ is the integer.

At first I thought it is just $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$. But I was wrong, the quotient group seems like something more trickier.

Could anyone show me to what other (more familiar group) is the one isomorphic to?

Comment: If $T$ is the torsion part of this group, then $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/\langle(4,-6)\rangle\cong T\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5):

This is an abelian group freely generated by two elements $a,b$ which satisfy $4a-6b=0$. Consider $a'=a-b$ and $b'=2a-3b$. Then $2b'=0$. We have $2a'-b'=b$ and $3a'-b'=a$. Thus we have found new generators. The old relation $4a=6b$ becomes $4(3a'-b')=6(2a'-b')$, which is equivalent to $2b'=0$.

Thus, we have the abelian group freely generated by two elements $a',b'$ such that $2b'=0$. This is the group $\mathbb{Z} ~\oplus ~\mathbb{Z}/2$.

More generally, one can show $\mathbb{Z}^2 / \langle (n,m) \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z} ~\oplus ~\mathbb{Z}/\langle \mathrm{gcd}(n,m) \rangle$ if $(n,m) \neq 0$. In general, the [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) provides an algorithm how to decompose a finitely generated abelian group into cyclic groups.